# Deploying web applications to a file share

Tags: deployment

what do you think about deploying the SharePoint IIS web sites to a Shared file location (`\\Fileserver\WWWRoot\Application1` for example) in contrast with deploying a copy locally to each Web Front End server (`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\application1` for example).

Deploying locally to WFEs can usually take time to copy physical files to the different WFEs and we make efforts in making them synched and sometimes we have problems because the two servers are not exactly the same and so on.

Are there any problems with the approach of deploying a Sharepoint IIS web site on a shared location path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OMG Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!**

Sorry to be over dramatic, but you will end up in a world of pain if you even attempt to do this. Use SharePoint WSP solutions to deploy to multiple WFEs. This process is well documented and very simple, especially if you use the excellent wspbuilder at CodePlex.

If you want some guidelines on SharePoint Development then pick up the [free Muhimbi SharePoint Development Guidelines.](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html)

Comment: yup, use WSP deployment!

Comment: SharePoint's Solution framework is meant to address deploying customizations across the farm.  

The org I'm working with currently takes this approach for their regular .net and cold fusion apps that are behind a load balancer, but the SharePoint apps apps rely on the standard SharePoint file structure.

Comment: heh... WSP is there for a reason. Its not 100% complete -for specific artifacts you will need to roll your own deployment timer job- but it works and its keeping your WFE's in sync. A thing to note is that i always recommend deploying to the **same WFE server every time you deploy**, since jobs can stall and you can get some real weird error scenarios (due to the way EXECADMSVCJOBS work) if you deploy to another WFE while same job is stalled on first WFE.